# How to prevent Convert in generated expression for type parameter is interface

Tags: c#, lambda

Here is the example code:

```cs
    public interface A
    {
        int MyProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public class B : A
    {
        public int MyProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public class C<T> where T : A
    {
        public Expression<Func<T, bool>> Expression { get; } = a => a.MyProperty > 0;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var cExpression = new C<B>();
            Console.WriteLine(cExpression.Expression.ToString());
        }
    }
```

The output of the expression: `a => (Convert(a, A).MyProperty > 0)`

And I decompiled the code above and I got below:

```cs
public class C<T> where T : A
{
    public Expression<Func<T, bool>> Expression { get; } = (T a) => ((A)a).MyProperty > 0;

}
```

As you can see, the compiler added a cast option `((A)a)` to the expression, that is what I **DO NOT** want, so the question is how can I tell the compiler **NOT** to do that?

Comment: Note: [The precise structure of the expression tree is implementation dependent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#evaluation-of-anonymous-function-conversions-to-expression-tree-types).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the compiler is emitting the `Convert` because of the possibility of the generic type parameter to be `struct` (value type), even though the manual approach demonstrated by another answer proves that it is unnecessary.

But is is what it is. So the only way currently to tell compiler to not generate `Convert` (cast) is to put `class` constraint:

```
where T : class, A
```

Now the output of the original sample expression will be `a => (a.MyProperty > 0)`

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to "tell the compiler" not to do this, but you can construct the expression tree directly:

```cs
public class C<T> where T : A {
    private static readonly MethodInfo s_propGetter = typeof(A).GetProperty(nameof(A.MyProperty)).GetMethod;

    public Expression<Func<T, bool>> Expr { get; private set; }

    public C() {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "a");
        Expr = Expression.Lambda(
            typeof(Func<T, bool>),
            Expression.GreaterThan(Expression.Property(param, s_propGetter), Expression.Constant(0)),
            new[] {param}
        ) as Expression<Func<T, bool>>;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if the implementing class uses explicit interface implementation, e.g. `public class B : A { int A.MyProperty { get; set; } }`? There is a reason for compiler emitting that cast. The proposed code besides being hard maintainable is based on assumption which is not guaranteed by the generic constraint.

Comment: This expression compiles and runs even with an explicit interface implementation. It also works when B is a struct.

Comment: Hmm, that's really interesting! So generally it's just a matter of removing compiler generated `Convert` then? By postprocessing the compiler generated expression tree :-/

Comment: Thank you @jfd348, although your answer could be a good solution for this one, Ivan's one is more make sense to me.